# Angularjs + Bootstrap: Google Page Insight test

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a simple html form and I want optimize the page load time. I'm using **AngularJS 1.3.0-beta15** and  **Twitter Bootstrap 3.2.0**.

I **solved the above-the-fold javascript/css issues** **deferring javascript** loading (defer directive in the  tag) and **inlined css** (bootstrap css code minified in  tag)

```
<head>
    [...]
    <style><?php include('bootstrap.min.css')?></style>
    <script defer src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

In the page body I used a simple form with validation directives. Example:

```
<form novalidate name="form" role="form">
    <div>
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Nombre*</label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="name" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" required/>
            <p ng-show="form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty" class="help-block">Nome compreso tra 3 e 20 caratteri</p>
                </div>
    [...]
```

the p tag conditionally displays the error for the input text by the **ng-show** directive.

Actually with this code the google page insight score is **97/100 on desktop** platform caused by ng-show elements.
The objective is to obtain 100/100 score on the desktop platform. The mentioned error from insights is the following:

[image]

In the screenshot ng-show elements are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-cloak?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Add the bit of CSS they include on that page to your site's CSS.  Then, add the 'ng-cloak' class to your p tags.  This will hide them until Angular loads.  Then Angular will remove the ng-cloak classes, and the items will be hidden based on the ng-show tags.

Comment: If anything in that link is necessary for your answer to be "complete", you should summarize it in your answer in case the link ever gets broken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like Server Side Rendering, this way the inspector would "see" all the real content in the first load.
Here is a project for this issue:
https://github.com/saymedia/angularjs-server

Comment: Can you explain the project please ?